# Node Webkit http crash

Tags: node-webkit

So I'm pulling remote JSON in to provide version number for an auto update procedure, I am able to pull the file just fine if I am online, I disabled my network adaptor to force no connectivity, and the app crashes to desktop.

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
    host: 'xxxx.xxxx.io',
    path: '/remote.json'
};

var req = http.get(options, function (res) {
var response = "";

    res.on("data", function (data) {
        response += data;
        var json = response;
        console.log("output:\n" + response);
    });
    res.on("error", function (e) {
        response += e;
        console.log(e);
    });
    res.on("uncaughtException", function (err) {
        response += err;
        console.log(err);
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        console.log("end:\n" + response); 
    });
});
```

I guess in my inexperience I am setting up the error checking incorrectly in some way? Could any of you guys provide the answer so the app doesn't crash on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this.

I needed to declare the on.error outside the `http.get` function.

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
   host: 'xxx.xxxxx.io',
   path: '/remote.json',
   method: 'get'
};

var res = http.get(options, function (res) {
   var response = "";

   res.on("data", function (data) {
   response += data;
});
res.on("end", function () {
    console.log("output:\n" + response); 
    var json = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(json.type);
  });
})

.setTimeout(3000, function() {
   console.log("ERROR: The connection timed out.");
   res.abort();
})

.on('error', (e) => {
  if (e.code === "ENOENT") {
    console.log("ERROR: There is no Internet connection.");
  }
});
```